# Mark a radio element as selected on page load and when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have the following javascript that calls a function on page load and on click of an element on my page. Is this the cleanest way to do this?

```
StyleSelectedPlan();

$(document).on('click', '.select-plan', function () {
    StyleSelectedPlan();
});

function StyleSelectedPlan() {
    $('.radio-wrapper').removeClass('selected');
    $('.select-plan:checked').closest('.radio-wrapper').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: `function() { f() }` can be just  `f` that's as much as you can simplify I think.

Comment: @elclanrs can you explain? not sure I understand

Answer (score 3):

As @elclanrs says, `function () { StyleSelectedPlan(); }` is redundant — you can just write `StyleSelectedPath`.

Since you're using jQuery, you should use [`$(document).ready(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), or better yet, `$(handler)`, to call the `handler` function when the page loads.

```js
$(StyleSelectedPlan).on('click', '.select-plan', StyleSelectedPlan);

function StyleSelectedPlan() {
    $('.radio-wrapper').removeClass('selected');
    $('.select-plan:checked').closest('.radio-wrapper').addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.radio-wrapper.selected { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="radio-wrapper"><input name="name" type="radio" class="select-plan" id="one"><label for="one">one</label></li>
  <li class="radio-wrapper"><input name="name" type="radio" class="select-plan" id="two"><label for="two">two</label></li>
  <li class="radio-wrapper"><input name="name" type="radio" class="select-plan" id="three" checked><label for="three">three</label> (preselected)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 for specifying `$(StyleSelectedPlan).on`